Error: Artifact Contains Unsupported 'android.support.design.widget' Reference After Migrating to AndroidX
I've been facing an issue in Android Studio after updating to Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch. Every time I try to build or rebuild my project, I encounter the following error:
The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.
I have already used Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX and manually checked the activities and layouts for any lingering android.support.* references, but the problem persists.
I'm using kotlin
Here are screenshots of the error message I'm encountering:
Beginning of error
The error
My build.gradle Project:
ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0"
    }
}

My build.gradle App:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.app'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-lite'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.sun.activation', module: 'javax.activation'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation("androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures-ktx:1.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.6")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.6")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.6")
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.7.3'
    constraints{
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0'
    }
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.3.0-alpha03'
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.0.1'

    def camerax_version = "1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.4"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.4"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    //noinspection KaptUsageInsteadOfKsp
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0'

    def media3_version = "1.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:$media3_version"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:$media3_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.7'

    //firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.1')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx')
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug")

    implementation("com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.6.1")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.33'
    implementation 'org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4'
}

My gradle.properties:
gradle.properties
Has anyone experienced this or have suggestions for resolving it? Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
I tried updating all my dependencies to their AndroidX supported variants but it didn't work. Also set android.enableJetifier=true and android.enableJetifier=false, still didn't work. I also tried to Invalidate Caches and Restart, but didn't work!
